# Using passport.js, my authentication and redirection to desired URL fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, session, passport.js

I am relatively new to JavaScript and aim to learn it not just through tutorials but also through projects.
This is the first time I have attempted to create a website with user signup and login, which means I have been met with concepts new to me such as authentication and session management. Specifically, I have dove into the usage of a library called passport.js.

The issue I am facing is the failure of authentication and redirection to my desired file/page 'dashboard.ejs'. I have seen many people with similar questions, but cant seem to find any answer that fully encompasses the solution or any solution at all, which could also be due to the lack of code they provide.

I will try not to make that mistake and provide as many relevant details as required. I just really hope someone can help me.

My end-goal: Successful redirection to dashboard.ejs, via route /dashboard.

Let's start with my project-structure.
My project-structure is as follows:

- Project Task Management(root folder)

  - controllers: userController.js
  - database: db.js, queries.js
  - node_modules: //...
  - public:

    - css: //...cssFiles
    - img: //...imgFiles
    - js : userSignup.js
  - routes: userRoutes.js
  - views:  dashboard.ejs, index.ejs, login.ejs, signup.ejs
  - index.js
  - passport.js
  - package-lock.json
  - package.json

I would like to make it clear, my signup's are successful, my logins are also successful, the data is stored in the database. However when it fails authentication which you will see below, failureRedirect: /.. leads it back to the signup page or login page.

Here is my passport configuration in the root folder, the file passport.js:

```js
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const pool = require('./database/db'); // Import your database connection module

// Configure the local strategy
passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy(
        {
            usernameField: 'email',
            passwordField: 'password',
        },
        async (email, password, done) => {
            try {
                console.log('Local Strategy: Attempting authentication');
                const query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1';
                const result = await pool.query(query, [email]);

                if (result.rows.length === 0) {
                    console.log('Local Strategy: User not found');
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect email or password' });
                }

                const user = result.rows[0];

                const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

                if (!passwordMatch) {
                    console.log('Local Strategy: Password does not match');
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect email or password' });
                }

                console.log('Local Strategy: Authentication successful');
                return done(null, user);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Local Strategy: Error during authentication:', error);
                return done(error);
            }
        }
    )
);

// Serialize and deserialize user information
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    console.log('Serialize User:', user);
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    try {
        const query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1';
        const result = await pool.query(query, [id]);

        if (result.rows.length === 0) {
            console.log('Deserialize User: User not found');
            return done(null, false);
        }

        const user = result.rows[0];
        console.log('Deserialize User:', user);
        return done(null, user);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Deserialize User: Error:', error);
        return done(error);
    }
});

module.exports = passport;
```

All the console log statements inside passport.js and all console.log statements in my code in other files as well related to authentication do not show, all I see is 'server listening on port xyz' It is as if the functions aren't even being called.

Here is my entry-point file (server), also in the root folder, index.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('./passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const path = require('path');
const dbQueries = require('./database/queries');
const pool = require('./database/db'); //importing db connection module
const app = express();

//Configure Express
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use('/img', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'img')));
app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'js'), { "extensions": ["js"] }));
app.use(express.json());

//Configure session middleware
app.use(
    session({
        secret: 'secrettexthere',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
    })
);

//Initialize passport and session:
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Ensure authenticated middleware
const ensureAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('ensureAuthenticated middleware called'); 
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect('/sign-in/login');
};


//Set EJS as the view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//Set PORT
const PORT = 3000;


//User Route
const userRoutes = require('./routes/userRoutes');
app.use('/users', userRoutes);

//Home Route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
});

//User Signup Route
app.get('/create-account/signup/orgAccount', (req, res) => {
    res.render('signup');
});

//User Login Route
app.get('/sign-in/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login');
});

//dashboard Route
app.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log('Dashboard route accessed by user:', req.user);
        const userId = req.user.id; // Assuming you have the user ID stored in req.user
        const query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1';
        const result = await pool.query(query, [userId]);

        if (result.rows.length === 0) {
            return res.status(404).json({ error: 'User not found' });
        }

        const user = result.rows[0];

        res.render('dashboard', { user });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching user data:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
});

//Starting Server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on PORT: ${PORT}`);
});
```

Here is my userRoutes.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const userController = require('../controllers/userController')
const router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');

//signup process:
router.post('/create-account/signup/orgAccount', userController.signup);

//login process;
router.post('/sign-in/login', userController.login);

module.exports = router;
```

and here is my userController.js, where the redirection essentially takes place:

```js
//controllers/userController.js
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const emailValidator = require('validator');
const passwordValidator = require('password-validator');
const pool = require('../database/db');
const dbQueries = require('../database/queries');
const passport = require('passport'); // Import passport for authentication

//Utility Functions:
function emailValidate(emailStr) {
    return emailValidator.isEmail(emailStr);
}

function passwordValidate(passwordStr) {
    const schema = new passwordValidator();
    schema
        .is().min(8) //8 minimum characters
        .has().uppercase() //atleast 1 uppercase char
        .has().digits() //atleast 1 digit
        .has().not().spaces(); //no spaces
    return schema.validate(passwordStr);
}

//SIGNUP
const signup = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, password, username, name, role } = req.body;

        //Checking Email Validity:
        if (!emailValidate(email)) {
            return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Please provide a valid email address' })
        }

        //Checking if User with same Email exists:
        const verifyExistingEmailQuery = dbQueries.getUserByEmailQuery;
        const existingEmailValue = [email];
        const existingEmailResult = await pool.query(verifyExistingEmailQuery, existingEmailValue);

        if (existingEmailResult.rows.length > 0) {
            return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Account already exists' });
        }

        //Checking Password Validity:
        if (!passwordValidate(password)) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                error: 'Password must be 8 characters and include an uppercase character and a number, without spaces'
            });
        }

        //Checking if User with same Username exists:
        const existingUsernameQuery = dbQueries.getUserByUsernameQuery;
        const existingUsernameValue = [username];
        const existingUsernameResult = await pool.query(existingUsernameQuery, existingUsernameValue);

        if (existingUsernameResult.rows.length > 0) {
            return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Username already exists' })
        }

        //Hashing password before storing it in database
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

        //Storing information in Users table.
        const query = dbQueries.createUserQuery;
        const values = [email, hashedPassword, username];

        const userResult = await pool.query(query, values);
        const user_id = userResult.rows[0].id;

        //Storing information in Organizations table.
        if (role === 'Business Owner') {
            const createOrgQuery = dbQueries.createOrganizationQuery;
            const createOrgValue = [name];

            const orgResult = await pool.query(createOrgQuery, createOrgValue);
            const organization_id = orgResult.rows[0].id;

            //Storing information in user_organization table.
            const createUserOrgQuery = dbQueries.createUserOrganizationQuery;
            const createUserOrgValue = [user_id, organization_id, role];

            await pool.query(createUserOrgQuery, createUserOrgValue);
        }

        passport.authenticate('local', {
            successRedirect: '/dashboard', //where I wish to go
            failureRedirect: '/create-account/signup/orgAccount', //where I end up going
            failureFlash: true
        })(req, res);
        //res.status(201).json({ message: 'User Created Successfully' });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error in user signup:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error, Signup failed', details: error.message });
    }
};

//LOGIN
const login = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;

        //Validate Email.
        if (!emailValidate(email)) {
            return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Please provide a valid email address' })
        }

        //Retrieve if user exists on the basis on their email
        const query = dbQueries.getUserByEmailQuery;
        const values = [email];
        const result = await pool.query(query, values);

        //If no user found:
        if (result.rows.length === 0) {
            return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid Email' });
        }

        const user = result.rows[0];
        //Compare Password with stored hash password
        const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

        if (!passwordMatch) {
            return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid Credentials' });
        }

        passport.authenticate('local', {
            successRedirect: '/dashboard',  //where I wish to go
            failureRedirect: '/sign-in/login', //where I end up going
            failureFlash: true
        })(req, res);
        //res.status(200).json({ message: 'Login Successfull' });

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error, Login Unsuccessful, Please try again later' });
    }
};

module.exports = {
    signup,
    login,
};
```

This is about all of the code I have related to authentication. I know I could've been a little more specific and concise, but apparently authentication has a lot to do with middleware ordering, etc. Hence, providing the bigger picture.